# Why was I suspended from SO chat for 24 hours?

Tags: support, chat

> your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 23 hours 53 minutes.

Can whoever suspended me provide some clarification regarding why this happened so I can learn and understand how to avoid potential problems in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a dup or not.

Comment: I guess the ban is due to the same reason.